# Is this question acceptable?

Tags: discussion

A littlie over a month ago, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651298/optimizing-vector-matrix-operations-in-c) in the C tag. As the question explicitly asks for off-site resources, I flagged it with the reason "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." However, the flag is still currently active, and, whats more, the post actually received two upvotes as well as an upvoted answer, which does in fact provide information on several off-site resources. Am I wrong in thinking this is a question that should be closed? If so, why?

Comment: IMO, it's not necessarily off-topic. Even though the OP asks for an off-site resource at the end, that doesn't seem to be the sole purpose of the question.

Answer (score 6):

You flagged it for closure, and it went into the close vote review queue.

That's a large queue; I wouldn't expect a resolution anytime soon.

I've edited the question to take out the explicit asking for an offsite resource; it's now (as far as I can see at least), an acceptable question.